# Animated emoji?

Tags: python, discord.py

When I try running this code. I get the following issue about something with animated emoji.
I am a newbie to python and help would be needed.

Code:

````
``` @commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx):
    i=1
    page1 = discord.Embed(title="page 1/2", description=f"This is the list of the command you can do, remember all of this is WIP(Work In Progress) also this bot run on discord.py package ver {discord.__version__}, have fun!", color=0x51C27D)
    page1.set_author(name="help", icon_url="https://imgur.com/B7bT6PP.png")
    page1.add_field(name="Fun", value="rs, bird, dog, cat",inline=False)
    page1.add_field(name="Unitity", value="info, uptime, whois", inline=False)
    page1.add_field(name="Moderation", value="warn", inline=False)
    page2 = discord.Embed(title='test')

    q=await ctx.send(embed=page1)
    await q.add_reaction("⬅️")
    await q.add_reaction("➡️")
    emoji=''
    while True:
        if emoji=='⬅️':
            i=1
            await q.edit(embed=page[i])
        if emoji=='➡️':
            i=2
            await q.edit(embed=page[i])```
````

Error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<Client.run.<locals>.runner() done, defined at /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py:545> exception=KeyError('animated')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 547, in runner
await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in start
await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 433, in connect
await self._connect()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 397, in _connect
await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 470, in poll_event
await self.received_message(msg)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 424, in received_message
func(data)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 410, in parse_message_reaction_add
emoji = PartialEmoji.with_state(self, animated=emoji_data['animated'], id=emoji_id, name=emoji_data['name'])
KeyError: 'animated'
```

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [an issue with discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2422) (caused by [a breaking change in Discord's API](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/812#issuecomment-554142833)) that should be [fixed](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/89bfd9cc2029d76e7580e14543ddc66ea182bf30) in [v1.2.5](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats_new.html#v1-2-5).

Comment: You can update now. It was [released to PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/1.2.5/) about a month ago.